# Facebook Like Button for Facebook Page for Blog

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I just created a Facebook page for my blog and am working on adding the like button. I suppose my first question is, is there already a like button added to a Facebook fan page itself and the code for the like button is so you can create a like button on a whole different page, like my Blogspot blog page? Since I'm the admin I'm not sure if I'm seeing whatever else is. If not, I'd like to add a like button to my Facebook page for people to like, but for the life of my cannot figure out where to paste the code. I know it says behind the  tag, but that doesn't mean anything to me. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

On the Facebook page is a like button of course already integrated, on that page you can get code for your Blog or website.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, you're looking for this plugin:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Specify the URL you want the like button to like, whether that be your blog post or your facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the facebook Like Box.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/